# ArrayList<Class> sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Is it any way to save ArrayList to sharedpreferences? Thank you

```
ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
activityList.add(Level1Activity.class);
activityList.add(Level2Activity.class);
activityList.add(Level3Activity.class);
activityList.add(Level4Activity.class);
activityList.add(Level5Activity.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered this to your other question but just in case, I'll re-write it here and explain it more a bit.

You can use `Gson` to convert your list into a `Json String` so that you can save it in `SharedPreferences`.

You will need to add `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` inside your app gradle dependencies to be able to use `Gson`.

**But**, you cannot simply parse the list using `Gson` to `Json` or viceversa when you use the `Class` class. In order to do so, you will need to create your own *serializer* and *deserializer* for it. Or you'll face this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.etc.etc.Level1Activity. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

So let's create a custom adapter that implements `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. Don't forget to put inside the angle brackets the type we're working with, which is `Class`.

**ClassAdapter class**

```
public class ClassAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Class>, JsonDeserializer<Class> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Class src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // Get our class 'src' name
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Class deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            // Get class
            return Class.forName(json.getAsString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // If class could not be found or did not exists, handle error here...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

To convert our list to `Json String` and save it inside `SharedPreferences`:

```
// Create new GsonBuilder and register our adapter for Class objects
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassAdapter());

// Initialize our list of levels (ie. classes)
List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
classes.add(Level1Activity.class);
classes.add(Level2Activity.class);
classes.add(Level3Activity.class);
classes.add(Level4Activity.class);
classes.add(Level5Activity.class);

// Create Gson from GsonBuilder and convert list to json
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(classes);

// Save json to SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("levels", json).apply();
```

And to retrieve the list back:

```
// Retrieve json from SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
String json = sharedPreferences.getString("levels", null);

// Handle here if json doesn't exist yet
if (json == null) {
    // ...
}

// Create new GsonBuilder and register our adapter for Class objects
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassAdapter());

// Create Gson from GsonBuilder and specify type of list
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Class>>(){}.getType();

// Convert json to list
List<Class> classes = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, i will try